# UPOS/OPOS DirectIO scanner remote triggering (Datalogic Heron HD3430) POSfor.NET

Tags: c#, .net, barcode-scanner, pos

How i can trigger a scanner remotely form my application ? the DirectIO commands provided with device does not contain any command could do that and with some search over google i found my device actually supports this kind of commands but i didn't find any find any thing useful.

Note 1:i am open to any suggestion could help.

Note 2: I've sent a request for the Technical support in Datalogic website but still no reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to describe the desired usage in detail.

For example, if you set the scanner to Always On or Stand Mode, reading can be started by writing the DeviceEnabled property to true, and you can stop reading by writing false to the DeviceEnabled property.

That way, it seems that software was triggered.

Comment: how i didn't thought of that! thanks a lot it's a very good idea.